# Unable to delete item using node in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i am having problem with removeCategory and error is that category always goes in if statement  though i am providing correct id in URL it dooes not remove catogry

```
const Category = require('../models/category')

exports.removeCategory = (req, res) => {
    const cat = req.cat
    if (!cat) {
        return res.json({
            error: true,
            message: 'no caterory found'
        })
    }
    cat.remove((err, cat) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(400).json({
                err: "Failed to Delete Category"
            })
            res.json({
                message: `Category ${cat} deleted Successfully`
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Are you dealing with a POST or GET request? Have you set up a body-parser?

Comment: So the `req.cat` variable is undefined or something like that, right? Where do you assign a value to `req.cat`? Also in the second `if` statement in `cat.remove` you call both `res.status(400).json(` and `res.json(` which will cause another error(Cannot send headers...) within the `if` statement. I believe the `res.json` should not be there.

Comment: hello sir thanks for comment i have done that and now my error is gone thanks for helpexports.removeCategory = (req, res) => {
    const cat = req.cat
    if (!cat) {
        return res.json({
            error: true,
            message: 'no caterory found'
        })
    }

    cat.remove((err, cat) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                err: "Failed to Delete Category"
            })
        }
    })
    res.json({
        message: `Category ${cat.name} deleted Successfully`
    })
}

Answer (score 0):

the best practics For delete a item, you must have the `id`, you need use the `Model` in this case `Category`

can you use **`findByIdAndRemove`**

for example.

```
const Category = require('../models/category')

exports.removeCategory = (req, res) => {
    const cat = req.cat
    const id =  req.id
    if (!cat) {
        return res.json({
            error: true,
            message: 'no caterory found'
        })
    }
    Category.findByIdAndRemove(id,(err, cat) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(400).json({
                err: "Failed to Delete Category"
            })
            res.json({
                message: `Category ${cat} deleted Successfully`
            })
        }
    })
}
```